# Creating a captive portal splash page for rasberry pi running hostapd as wifi access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wireless-access-point, mobile-phone

I've created an access point on a raspberry pi which users can connect to from their phones to access a local site on the pi.  However, I'm trying to reduce the user flow from this:

- connect to wifi hotspot
- open browser
- go to url configured in pi (http://examplepi.com)

to this:

- connect to wifi hotspot
- automatically open browser to http://examplepi.com OR open captive portal that links to http://examplepi.com

Basically, the point is not so that the users have to accept some terms, but that they will just have to connect to the access point and be shuffled along to the url instead of having to know about the url already and go through the extra step of typing it in.  I was wondering if there is some kind of implementation I can use for this or instructions on how to set up a custom captive portal (one that is **not in-browser** but rather pops up right when you connect to the AP).

### EDIT

Using hostapd/dnsmasq to run the access point.

Just to clarify what I'm going for: either a popup like the ones you see at Starbucks etc. when you connect to their wifi (which I can then customize to show a link to where they need to go), or somehow auto-directing the user to a specific url in the browser (which is the ultimate destination)

Comment: What are you using to host the AP? hostapd?

Comment: Yes, hostapd/dnsmasq

Comment: PacketFence has a great opensource solution for captive-portal.

https://packetfence.org/

Comment: Can you post your dnsmasq.conf?